# How to fix extra run in loop?

Tags: c#, .net

I create an object in which values from 3 rows and I need to loop through 3 lines and add values from this object (rowsCmd).

```
private void CalculateDist()
{
    var Unique= Cursor.GetFieldValue<int>("Unique");
    var document = new HeadersRepository().Get(Unique);
    if (document == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    var rowsRepository = new RowsRepository(document);
    var rowList = rowsRepository.GetRows();

    var cmd = SqlClient.Main.CreateCommand(string.Format(
        @"select DOC.Unique, DOC.Number from DOC where DOC.Unique =@Unique order by DOC.Number"), new { Unique });

    var rowsCmd = cmd.ExecObjects(new
    {
        Unique= 0,
        Number= 0,
    });


    foreach (var row in rowList)
    {
        foreach (var rowCmd in rowsCmd)
        {
            row.Number = rowCmd.Number;
            row.Number= rowCmd.Number;
        }
    }
}
```

if i have 2 rows this code will execute 4 time, but need only 2. how to make a loop which will pass through each rows in my list rowList and put data from object rowsCmd in 1 loop

Comment: You have nested foreach loops, meaning the inner loop will run fully for every iteration through the outer one. `row.Number` will be overwritten repeatedly and the last one wins.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with "_this code will execute 4 time_". What is "_this code_"? The body in the inner foreach loop? Of course the body of the inner foreach loop will execute rowList.Count * rowsCmd.Count times. Which then makes me totally confused when you say "_but need only 2_". I have no idea what you want/try to achieve. Your problem description is very confusing. (Side note: The two code lines in the inner foreach body are just the same assignment. What's up with that?)

Comment: For each row. For each rowCmd set the value of row.Number twice.
Thus if I have multiple rowsCmd I will set the value of row.Number twice to the value of the first rowCmd. Then twice to the value of the second rowCmd. And so on.

Comment: This means that I first read all values into the object and try to add them (values from the object) to each row in rowList. BUT I don’t know how to write value obj without a second loop. value from obj I can only get in the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code always set row values with rowsCmd list's last element. So it is a wrong code segment.

For your purpose you can use for loop instead of foreach loop.

```
for(int i=0; i< rowList.Count; i++){
   rowList[i].Number = rowsCmd[i].Number;
}
```